# Invalid result for supplementaryViewForElementKind

Tags: ios, objective-c, collections, uicollectionview, uikit

I'm trying to reset my `collectionView`'s subviews frames and `layoutAttributes` whenever invalidating the layout for the bottom edge is necessary in `layoutSubviews()`. However every once in awhile 0.5% of the time. I'm getting a crash with the error:

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
> the view returned from -collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath (UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader,<NSIndexPath: 0xe4630e2be7f8d8ab> {length = 2, path = 14 - 0}) was not retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: or is nil (<UICollectionReusableView: 0x15b946bc0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x282f39820>>)

I'm guessing this has something to do with the plain `UICollectionReusableView()` I am returning in the `dequeueSupplementaryView` whenever there is no header needed for the section. Have been staring at this for awhile so I figured someone might be able to help...

```
for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes in attributesInBounds) {
    if (!CGRectIntersectsRect(attributes.frame, self.bounds)) {
        continue;
    }

    UICollectionReusableView *view = nil;

    switch (attributes.representedElementCategory) {
        case UICollectionElementCategoryCell:
            view = [self cellForItemAtIndexPath:attributes.indexPath];
            break;
        case UICollectionElementCategorySupplementaryView:
            view = [self supplementaryViewForElementKind:attributes.representedElementKind atIndexPath:attributes.indexPath];
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    [view setFrame:attributes.frame];
    [view applyLayoutAttributes:attributes];
}
```

Comment: I'm also guessing here, but I suspect there are still some batch updates performing ... can you reproduce the error consistently? How to fix it ... not sure, but maybe schedule what you do on main to ensure it runs after whatever is under way finishes.

Comment: @skaak It seems to happen when scrolling through the collection view or rotating the screen. Could it be a threading issue on underneath how `.layoutSubviews` is called/handled? I would think Apple would have encountered and solved it by now though. Seems to be happening across iOS versions

Comment: Don't give Apple too much credit - that is another story that I had to remove for the sake of space. Anyhow - guessing here, again, but I think the way to solve your problem is as follows. Your problem, I understand, is that sometimes you want no header cell and sometimes you want one. Why not then override the ```collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:``` in the delegate. Then you can build the logic in there and return 0 or some value depending on that logic and you can also request a refresh if the view doesn't redraw by itself. I think that is the better approach here.